# Dropdown List deduction

Tags: google-sheets, filter, dropdown

I have a list of 100 employees and 50 dropdowns. I want to select some of the employees in the dropdowns but I want to prevent the user from choosing the same employee more than once.
I want to deduct the chosen employees from the possible dropdown answers. How can I manage to do so?

I tried to filter out the selected employees but it shows an ugly warning sign for those who were selected

you can view my spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bzMPC3-SDOjsgZVXHQgmfBnkiTEsa1Pei7p_DybIebY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's not possible since the Data Validation rule is comparing the cell value with Column C, where you remove that same value. Have you considered doing this with Apps Script?

Comment: best way to do this would be to use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d3r3.png

Comment: @Jescanellas tried to do it with a script, but It's way too complicated for me. How can I do it with Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Simple Trigger [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to automatically do the job:

> The onEdit(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value
>   of any cell in a spreadsheet [...]

It's not exactly the same as you had before, because the selected values will still be displayed on the list. They just will be removed if they are repeated.

The only change you should do is to **remove the current Data Validation from Column D and set a new one with values from Column A**.

```
function onEdit(event){

  if (event.range.getColumn() == 4){   //Run only if the edited cell is from column D

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var selection = sheet.getRange("D2:D22").getValues(); 
    var editedRow = event.range.getRow(); //Gets the edited row

    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++){ 

      //If some value from D is equal to the edited value but in a different Row (so it ignores the inputted value)
      if ((i + 2) != editedRow &&  selection[i][0] == event.value){ 

          sheet.getRange(event.range.getA1Notation()).setValue(""); //Change the new value to empty

      }

    }
  }
}
```

The function will run every time you select an item in the column D.

**Result:**

[image]

**References:**

- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Thank you very much. that helped me a lot! I really wanted to view a list of the unselected employees but that will do for now.